# Java dependencies according to operation system?

Tags: java, preprocessor, native

So, i have a lot of projects based on java. It uses a lot of native libraries. All of them(projects/libraries) are in the same repository. And of corse for each OS are different dlls/jars
The idea is to change which of them would be import according to OS. So is it possible without  using Maven,Gradle.. e.t.c? I think it would be look like using c++ preprocessor..

UPT
Sorry for misinformation, We`r using Ant.. So would be nice to know is any solution with it?

Comment: It is not clear what you are talking about here.  Are you talking about compile / build time dependencies, or runtime dependencies?  And if you are not using Maven, Gradle or Ant, what build tool are you using?

Comment: I am talking about build dependencies.
I am no such experienced in build tools, and can look foolish, but we use standart eclipse tools i think..

Comment: For simplicity, I would ship all the DLLs and pick which one you want to load at runtime. Personally, I would avoid using native libraries unless you really need to.

Comment: UPT
We`r using Ant, sorry for misinformation..

Comment: We have a lot of terminals and a repo, the idea is after downloading all projects should work correctly without "human being" help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal job is to use Maven to define all dependencies that you need for all operating systems. So your project will contain all the necessary libs for each operating system.
And for using libs in code dynamically, you detect the os programmatically with the instruction :

```
  System.getProperty("os.name")
```

And you define a switch loop or an "if series" for example of libs invocation.
Here is an example that you can edit:

```
public class OSValidator {

private static String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(OS);

    if (isWindows()) {
        System.out.println("This is Windows");
    } else if (isMac()) {
        System.out.println("This is Mac");
    } else if (isUnix()) {
        System.out.println("This is Unix or Linux");
    } else if (isSolaris()) {
        System.out.println("This is Solaris");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Your OS is not support!!");
    }
}

public static boolean isWindows() {
    return (OS.indexOf("win") >= 0);
}

public static boolean isMac() {
    return (OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0);
}

public static boolean isUnix() {
    return (OS.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("nux") >= 0 || OS.indexOf("aix") > 0 );
}

public static boolean isSolaris() {
    return (OS.indexOf("sunos") >= 0);
}
```

}

Comment: I didt write, but we need "build" solution.. Your`s is "runtime" if i understood correctly..

Comment: exactly, what i understood from you question is that the OS will matter in the runtime not the build. because generally we know on which os we are compiling/building but the OS is unknown for runtime step

Comment: I think that we will use runtime solution, but i`ll try to convince my boss use Maven (: Thank`s a lot!

Comment: According to [this info from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2002/tn2110.html) the correct way to identify the Mac OS X is to do `System.getProperty("os.name").contains("OS X")`. But I've seen your version as well in multiple places on the Internet so don't really know what to believe.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of having build tools is that we do not have to take care of the various dependencies on our own. So I would still suggest you have a look at Maven build profiles.

For example

```
<profiles>
<profile>
<activation>
  <os>
    <name>Windows XP</name>
    <family>Windows</family>
    <arch>x86</arch>
    <version>5.1.2600</version>
  </os>
</activation>
...
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Also do have a look at the following http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Is it possible to create something like this with Ant?